# OnChange get php variable and start query

Tags: php, jquery, onchange

I am doing project on PHP and I have this problem...

This is a sample of my select

```
<select onchange="">
     <option value="1">option1</option>
     <option value="2">option2</option>
     <option value="3">option3</option>
</select>
```

So when user change the option I must query

```
SELECT data FROM mydb WHERE id = 'onchange'
```

Then

```
<input type="text" value="(...php data)">
```

Comment: Eh. What? A tad unclear, but none the less, you need to use AJAX.

Comment: use ajax for this. it runs on the background so you dont need to change screen of what ever. then when the request is a success you can set the response as text value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ajax for this. it runs on the background so you dont need to change screen of what ever. then when the request is a success you can set the response as text value

```
var id="1";
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'yourphppage',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        idofrow:id
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $('input:text').val(data[0].message);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert(data);

    }
});
```

This is a samle of ajax request you can use this and just change the other fields as need when the query is success you can retrieve that data in the success you can manipulate what data you want to use you can return json,text.

In your php page you can retrieve the id as

`$id = ($_POST['idofrow']);`

you can then you this id to select like this

`SELECT * FROM table where rowid = $id`

and you can just echo the result.

[Docu here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

Give your select,textbox a id or class(i am giving id) and  then

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select#yourselectID').change(function(){
        var variable = $( "#yourselectID" ).val();
         $.ajax
            ({ 
                url: 'your-url.php',
                data: { variable : variable},
                type: 'post',
                success: function(result)
                {
                    $('#yourtextboxID').val(result);
                }
            });
    });
});
</script>
```

In your-url.php

```
$sql="SELECT data FROM mydb WHERE id = '".$_post['variable']."'";
```

This would give you desired result.